# How to open the Preview window maximised by default?

Tags: preview

Does anyone know how to open Preview.app with the window maximised by default, in order to automatically fit the screen? 
Right now, the Preview window opens almost half screen and I think it is quire annoying to enlarge it manually. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Only option is to use the key combination option (alt) + space to fullscreen the document.

**update: If you do alt+space you will go fullscreen, hold the alt button and you zoom 100% of the file

Comment: But this is **Quicklook**  not **Preview**.

Comment: Your right, but quicklook is faster and easier.